# req.body for ID is always undefined but my client side is getting the right value by jQuery .click() call

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I swear it was working few days ago, so this behavior is really strange for me. Let me show you my code on client side

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
       alert(event.currentTarget.id+"------"+event.currentTarget.value);
       $.post( "/vote", {id:event.currentTarget.id,count:event.currentTarget.value}, $(this).serialize(),
           function(res) {
           }
       );
    })                  
})
```

As you can see, I tried to passed both `id` and `value` back to server once the button clicked. So far everything here is good because I can see the alert pop-up on screen with the correct id number and value `(Output example -> aaa------23)`. Now take a look on my server side code.

```
app.post('/vote', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    var count = req.body.count;

    console.log("id: " + id);
    console.log("count: " + count);

    res.sendStatus(200);
    res.end();
});
```

When execute to the line `var id = req.body.id`, the system returns

> `TypeError: Cannot read property id of undefined`.

`count` will have the same result.

Is there anything obvious I am missing here? Because I swear it was working before and I haven't touch this part of the code since then. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use `body-parser` and it is defined before your route.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

and then include it before you define routes:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/vote', function(req, res) {
   var id = req.body.id;
   var count = req.body.count;

   console.log("id: " + id);
   console.log("count: " + count);

   res.sendStatus(200);
   res.end();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I am using multer. Since my other page with form submit is working - req.body or req.file has no error, so I am quite sure multer parsing part is ok. Still thanks for your advice.

Comment: On second thought, you might be right. Multer can only be identified by passing  "enctype="multipart/form-data", or maybe that is not true. Can multer and body-parser co-exist? thanks.

Comment: You are correct. I do need to keep body-parser to make this part of the code working. Although I don't know if any risk to have them co-exist, but it solved my current problem. I will accept it as an answer. Appreciated your help.

Comment: Hi @RogerMW, for file upload you need to add this line too: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`